# laravel link does work but button does not

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

In laravel i have link called ZOEKEN it goes to 'zoekenindex'. It works

```
  <li> {{HTML::link('zoekenindex','ZOEKEN')}}</li>
```

But instead of a a link i want a button:

```
 <button href="{{ route('zoekenindeze') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
```

this outputs: "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "zoekenindex" as such route does not exist."

I don't get why, because the route works when i use the link code.

Anyone got a idea why this is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel don't find any name route called `zoekenindex` in your route file.

Create a name route:

```
Route::get('zoekenindex', array('as' => 'zoekenindex', 'uses' => 'yourController@index'))
```

**Your button**: bootstrap by default will create the button. don't worry about the link.

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('zoekenindex') }}" class="btn btn-default">Left</a>
```

Laravel helper:

```
{{ link_to_route('zoekenindex', 'Left', null, array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
```

**or**, if you don't like to create a name route, use the following:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('zoekenindex') }}" class="btn btn-default">Left</a>
```

Laravel helper:

```
{{ link_to('zoekenindex', 'Left', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know bootstrap would create the button just by adding the `btn` class to an anchor tag.  Switching that actually fixed the small issue I was having with the button not "popping back up" after clicking it to initiate a download.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button href="{{ url('zoekenindeze') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
```

and it will point to the zoekenindeze route

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5

```
{!! HTML::linkRoute('admin.users.edit', $user->display_name, array($user->id), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
```